# xsim: question/solution throws 'environment already defined'

Tags: xsim

In `xsim` I would like to combine a `question` environment with a `solution` environment. I am getting an error:

> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ! ! LaTeX error:
>   "xparse/environment-already-defined" !  ! Environment 'solution'
>   already defined! !  ! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further
>   information. !  ! For immediate help type H .

I used to name my environments `question/answer`, but I'd like to use the name `solution` instead of `answer` --- everything else unchanged. Is it possible?

This is what works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question,
  solution-env = answer, % would like to rename answer -> solution 
  exercise-name = Question,
  solution-name = Answer,
  exercise-template = default,
  solution-template = default
}
\xsimsetup{answer/print=true} % would like to rename answer -> solution 
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
My Question
\end{question}
\begin{answer}% would like to rename answer -> solution 
My Answer
\end{answer}% would like to rename answer -> solution 
\end{document}
```

This is what doesn't work, after renaming `answer` to `solution`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question,
  solution-env = solution, % IF NAMED 'solution' throws an error!
  exercise-name = Question,
  solution-name = Answer,
  exercise-template = default,
  solution-template = default
}
\xsimsetup{solution/print=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
My Question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
My Answer
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**  short answer: `solution` is a reserved keyword of the `xsim` package. Can't use it. Thanks **egreg**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `solution` environment is predefined. Why don't you simply change the printed names?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name=Question,
  solution/print=true,
  solution/name=Answer,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
My Question
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
My Answer
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg, my question really was about using the ``question`` and ``solution`` environments together, as in ``begin{question}, etc.``  and ``begin{solution}, etc.``. Not about the name of the environment as it gets printed. Sorry about the confusion. My workaround was to use a name other than ``solution`` (my first choice word). Examples of alternatives ``hint``, ``key``, ``solutionX``, ``mcSolution`` and ``solutions`` (with an ``s``). You may want to add this to your answer or if you can hack ``xsim`` to allow setting ``solution-env=solution`` that would be best. Thanks again.

Comment: @PatrickT I tried undefining `solution`, but it doesn't work. Why is `answer` not good?

Comment: Thanks for your help egreg. I'm already using ``answer`` for an environment that could not easily map to the ``xsim`` syntax. I was basically looking for a synonym to ``answer`` and I thought ``solution`` was the simplest, but hadn't realize that it's a reserved keyword of the ``xsim`` package (does the manual mention that?). I'm now using ``mc/hint`` with ``xsim`` and keeping my old ``answer`` for my other environment.  I have hundreds of questions/answers, so it would be time consuming to rewrite it all to fit ``xsim``. It was basically a stupid question with a simple workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT It might be a feature request: an option for not defining the default environments. It would be very easy to implement.

Comment: Oh why good idea, here: https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/31